# How to use a variable as a condition for retrieving data from a darabase in Anylogic 8.7

Tags: java, anylogic

I wrote the following code in a Variable in Anylogic:
but I've got the following Error:
Description: Syntax error on token "=", ; expected.

I think there's a problem with the loop i've entered. because if you delete the loop, the problem would be solved immediately.
I think it's a problem with inserting the "i" variable in the Query: eq(i)

```
    help=for (i=0 ; i<=35 ; i++);{
get_Main().cost=(int) selectFrom(rs_table)
    .where(rs_table.tr.eq(1))   
    .where(rs_table.x.eq(i))
    .firstResult(rs_table.impact);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the semi-colon after the for loop definition:

```
help=for (i=0 ; i<=35 ; i++) {
get_Main().cost=(int) selectFrom(rs_table)
.where(rs_table.tr.eq(1))   
.where(rs_table.x.eq(i))
.firstResult(rs_table.impact);
}
```

And if you haven't added i in the model, add "int" before it the first time:

```
help=for (int i=0 ; i<=35 ; i++) {
get_Main().cost=(int) selectFrom(rs_table)
.where(rs_table.tr.eq(1))   
.where(rs_table.x.eq(i))
.firstResult(rs_table.impact);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that one before. It doesn't work neither by omitting  ";" nor by adding "int". Although I had been added the "i" variable by a module independently and set it as an "int" integer Variable.